# Laravel Blade Changing Active Class Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

How will I change the active class in twitter bootstrap when i visit another page with Laravel Blade Templating ?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example this might can help

You could define a variable in your blade template

```
 <?php $nav_profile = 'active'; ?>

    @extends ('layouts.app')

    @section ('content')
..
..
    @endsection
```

And then in the layouts file;

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $nav_home or ''  }}"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" class="{{ $nav_profile or ''  }}"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" class="{{ $nav_messages or '' }}"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, if the page includes a variable called nav_profile then insert 'active' into the class. The 'or 'part inserts an empty string if the variable is not present.

Comment: You can also use the `Request::is('home')` etc helper to check the current page. This allows you to not have to make a variable for each page.

Comment: So im fairly new to laravel. How will I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution for this problem. This solution has very simple trick.

And it will work for all links throughout the page.

```
<script>
  function addActiveClass(){
    var objs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');          // take all 'a' tags
    for(var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++){
      if(objs[i].href == window.location.href){             // check if the user is on this link
        objs[i].className = objs[i].className + " active";  // add additional 'active' class
      }
    }
  }

  addActiveClass();
</script>
```

Adding this code to the end of your page will do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Active package](https://github.com/tuytoosh/active), these days you can simply do it like this:

```
class="@active('home')"
```

It has a lot of other options for example for wildcard activation. For example if you want to activate all routes of admin panel, you can do like this:

```
class="@active('admin.*')"
```